# how to insert "X" between rows of dataframe based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| ID | Date | dummy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-03 20:00:00 |  |
| 1 | 2019-01-04 14:30:00 | x |
| 2 | 2019-01-04 16:00:00 | x |
| 3 | 2019-01-04 20:00:00 | x |

wanted to know how would I be able to insert "X" into the dummy column based on date selection.  For example I would like to input an "X" starting 2019-01-04 14:30:00 to 2019-01-04 20:00:00

I know I could just select `df\["dummy"\]\[1:3\] = "X"` to accomplish this but not too sure how to grab from the dates column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to create a boolean Series for dates between your boundaries, and [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select between `'x'` and `''`:

```
df['dummy'] = np.where(df['Date'].between('2019-01-04 14:30:00',
                                          '2019-01-04 20:00:00'),
                       'x', '')
```

Or, with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['Date'].between('2019-01-04 14:30:00', '2019-01-04 20:00:00'),
       'dummy'] = 'x'
```

Output:

```
   ID                Date dummy
0   0 2019-01-03 20:00:00      
1   1 2019-01-04 14:30:00     x
2   2 2019-01-04 16:00:00     x
3   3 2019-01-04 20:00:00     x
```

Comment: Cool!   thank you ver much.  worked perfeclty!  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @aaaahhhhhh, you should mark this as the correct answer then.

Comment: how do you do that?  apologies.  I just started using stack overflow.  I am trying to look for the button

Comment: @aaaahhhhhh here is the [relevant documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)